# Density of bounded continuous functions in $L^1$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, metric-spaces, lebesgue-integral

Let $X$ be a metric space, $\mathbb P$ a Borelian probability measure on $X$ and $L^1 = L^1(X,\mathcal B(X) , \mathbb P)$ the associated Lebesgue space. Also let $C_b = C_b(X,\mathbb R)$ be the set of continuous bounded functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$.

**Under what hypothesis on $X$ and $\mathbb P$ the set $C_b$ is dense in $L^1$ ?**

If $X$ is a topological space that is Hausdorff locally compact and $\mu$ is locally finite regular then I know that $C_c$ the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ with compact support is dense in $L^p(X,\mathcal B(X),\mu)$, $p \in [1,\infty)$.

The counter example I know of $C_c$ not being dense in $L^1$ does not work because of the compacity. Take $X$ infinite dimensional normed vector space, then $C_c = \{ 0 \}$. Then if we ask in addition $X$ Polish and $\mu$ probability measure we get a counter example.

The space $C_b$ being bigger and without any notion of compacity I expect less hypothesis on $X$ and $\mu$ than the one I gave for $C_c$. To allow $C_b$ to be a subset of $L^1$ we should take finite measure, thus without loss of generality I choosed a probability measure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer: no further hypothesis required**

If $O \subset X$ is open the sequence of continuous bounded functions defined by
$$
f_n(x) = \min(nd(x,O^c),1)
$$
converges pointwise to $1_O$ with domination $1 \in L^1(\mathbb P)$. So if $\mathbb P$ is outer regular we are done.

It turns out $\mathbb P$ is outer regular because any finite Borel measure is outer regular. See for example [proposition 2.3 page 3.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiv_LOUgpH0AhU9g_0HHeQxAywQFnoECAYQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mat.unb.br%2Fcioletti%2Fitmg-02-2012%2Fpdfs%2FProbability%2520measures%2520on%2520metric%2520spaces%2520-%2520Onno%2520van%2520Gaans.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1KwExa-SRU8mb9AXNNOtB-)